# Parameters not set when posting with Angular

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC web API endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
public ReadQuoteForClientIdResponse ReadQuoteForClientId
        (
        ReadQuoteForClientIdRequest readQuoteForClientIdRequest
        )
{
    return new ReadQuoteForClientIdResponseMapper().Map
    (
        new ReadQuoteWorkflowHelper().ReadForClientId(readQuoteForClientIdRequest.ClientId)
    );
}
```

The endpoint takes a `ReadQuoteForClientIdRequest` as a parameter

```
public class ReadQuoteForClientIdRequest
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to do a simple post and is reaching the controller, but for some reason `ClientId` is always 0.

```
function quoteGridController($scope, $http) {
$scope.quotes = [];

$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$http.post("http://localhost:57048/service/Quote/ReadQuoteForClientId", { "ClientId": "2" })
    .success(function(data) {

    })
    .error(function(data) {
    alert("Error occured " + data);
});
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I passed my parameters to `$.Param` which fixed the problem

```
$http.post("http://localhost:57048/service/Quote/ReadQuoteForClientId", $.param({ "ClientId": 2 }))
    .success(function(data) {

    })
    .error(function(data) {
    alert("Error occured " + data);
});
```